# How to create a constant static array of strings in c#?

Tags: c#, constants

I'd like to offer a list of constants within my DLL.

Example usage:

```
MyDLL.AddHouse( HouseName, MyDll.HOUSETYPES.Big)
MyDLL.AddHouse( HouseName, MyDll.HOUSETYPES.Small)
```

Tried:

```
public static readonly string[] HOUSETYPES =
{
  "Big", "Small"
};
```

But that only gets me:

```
MyDLL.AddHouse( HouseName, MyDll.HOUSETYPES.ToString())
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason not to use an enum?

Answer (score 5):

Try using an enumeration.  In C# this is the best option.

As the enumerations are strongly typed, instead of having an API that takes a string, your api will take a value of the type of your enumeration.

```
public enum HouseTypes
{
   Big,
   Small
}
MyDll.Function(HouseTypes Option)
{
}
```

You can then call this code via the enum

```
{
   MyDll.Function(HouseTypes.Big)
}
```

FYI as a coding style all caps in C# is reserved for constants only.

Comment: I don't think all caps is recommended even for Constants.

Comment: Correct - the guidelines from Microsoft say that all capitals should never be used in C#.   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f75d6cb4-084f-4f2a-95c0-6d7f1b67c978

Answer (score 4):

```
public static class HouseTypes
{
    public const string Big = "Big";
    public const string Small = "Small";
}
```

It is a good idea to follow .NET naming standards for naming your classes and variables. E.g. class will be called HouseTypes (Pascal Case) and not HOUSETYPES (Upper case).